# How to test model with HABTM associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I need to test a model with HABTM association. My factory looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do |f|
    body "Some awesome text"
    after(:build) {|article| article.users = [create(:user)]}
  end
end
```

How to test `article` creation without `users` association later in such way:

```
it "is not a valid article without users" do
  article = build(:article, users: []) #doesn't work
  expect(article.valid?).to eq(false)
end
```

Comment: `after(:build)` runs AFTER your build is called. So even though you assign `users: []`, it will get created and assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off creating a sub-factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do |f|
    body "Some awesome text"

    factory :article_with_users do
      after(:build) {|article| article.users = [create(:user)]}
    end
  end
end
```

Then test by:

```
it "don't create article without users associations" do
  article = build(:article) #doesn't work
  expect(article.valid?).to eq(false)
end

it "do create article with users associations" do
  article = build(:article_with_users)
  expect(article.valid?).to eq(true)
end
```

This, however, depends on your validation setup in your models as well.

*it don't, it do* :)